# Matching 2 almost same dataframes to be equal

Tags: r

I have a df1 like this:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 4
text 5
```

And another one df2 like this:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 5
```

The problem is my dfs are almost the same, they have many rows and I can find the one that is additional to the first df in order to know who is it?

Is there any possible option to compare the two dfs and find the one row it is the difference between them?

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); anti_join(df1, df2)`

Comment: Thanks for the vote up but not I am realizing that my solution could be weak for different data, if the case could you `dput` a piece of your data in order to let me test my base R solution?

Comment: Another option using the devel version of data.table would be `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[!df2, on=names(df1)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `rbind` the two and then find the non-duplicated rows.

For example, if you have data frames `a` and `b` then

```
x <- rbind(a, b)
x[!duplicated(x) & !duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE), ]
#     V1 V2
# 4 text  4
```

Or if you prefer, you can use `dplyr::setdiff()`, which has a data frame method.

```
dplyr::setdiff(a, b)
#     V1 V2
# 1 text  4
```

where

```
a <- read.table(text = "text 1
text 2
text 3
text 4
text 5", header = FALSE)

b <- a[-4, ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) solution:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.frame(V1=rep('text',5),V2=1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(V1=rep('text',4),V2=c(1:3,5))
setkey(setDT(df1))[!df2]
##      V1 V2
## 1: text  4
```

Comment: If you don't supply any arguments to `setkey`, it keys on every column. So you only need to write `setkey(setDT(df1))`.

Comment: Thanks! That's convenient.

Comment: I actually didn't catch anything about that in the documentation for `?setkey`, not sure why I know that. Perhaps @Arun could mark that for a quick write-up. Anyway, if you look at the code for `setkey` you'll see: `if (!length(cols)) cols = colnames(x)`, which is where this happens.

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution.

```
 df1[-merge(df1, df2)[,2], ]
    V1 V2
4 text  4
```

or:

```
 df1[-which(df1[ , 2] %in% df2[, 2]), ]
    V1 V2
4 text  4
```

#### Edit

after thinking about a base R solution I realized that my previous solutions might be weak with some data. Here is a more robust solution I think.

```
 df1[ !df1$V2 %in% merge(df1, df2)[,2, drop = T], ]
    V1 V2
4 text  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Base package:

```
df <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "V2", all.x = TRUE)
df[!complete.cases(df), ]
```

Output:

```
  V2 V1.x V1.y
4  4 text <NA>
```

With `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM df1 
      LEFT JOIN 
      df2 USING (V2)
      WHERE df2.V1 IS NULL")
```

Output:

```
    V1 V2   V1
1 text  4 <NA>
```